# Facebook SDK post with BOTH place AND picture

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, checkin

I'm using Facebook's latest SDK for Android.

Is it possible to post a status with BOTH place AND picture?

My bundle looks like this:

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
postParams.putString("message", "Hi there!!");
postParams.putString("picture", "http://www.peleozen.net/pics/2_bus_face_logo.jpg");
postParams.putString("place", "204519339582365");
```

When I make the request, it results in a status with only the picture.

Making the request without a picture results in a checkin

So...is it possible to do both?

Comment: Try posting it without the place to make sure the place tag is valid. My suspicion is that your place tag is invalid, which is why it isn't showing a place as checked in.

Comment: It is valid...It works just fine with only the place tag..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post to the /me/photos endpoint, so in a sense you're posting a photo, adding a location to it and the caption is the message. So as an example, if using the latest SDK, you could take a look at the HelloFacebookSample and make the following changes to the postPhoto method to try this out:

```
....
        Bundle params = request.getParameters();
        params.putString("message", "Hi there!!");
        params.putString("place", "166793820034304");
        request.setParameters(params);
        Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
....
```

For reference, see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos

Comment: Yes, this actually works!
Edit: note that it works on any facebook graph object that has a location attached to it